# Windows App / IE WebApp GET Request only sent once

Tags: c#, angularjs, internet-explorer, http

Just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468565/get-request-sent-to-rest-api-only-first-time-in-ie10) I am having some super weired problems with IE 10+, c# and Windows Phone 8.1

Here is my scenario:
I have a simple REST Api running on a Node.js server (on a Raspberry Pi) to control some Relays. I built an AngularJS App aswell as a Windows Store App as client.
The Angular Client works fine and super-fast ... on chrome and Firefox etc. But on IE11 evry GET-request only works once per session. e.g. if I hit the "toggle Relay1" button a request is called that results in toggling the Relay (server side toggle-logic). If I hit it again IE doesnt call the request again. Evry other browser does.
After a little bit of hacking around I found out that the issue gets solved as soon as I open the IE Dev Tools. If I close them it wont work again. Has anybody an explaination for that?

That was part one of my problem.
Now I would not have done a new Post on that topic if the story wont continue.
In the Windows Store App (Debugging it on my Lumia 930) I ran into a very similar problem. First I thought my App deadlocks after the first call. I applied [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) workaround to be sure its not a deadlock.

So now I'm stuck because my native Windows Phone App behaves just like the crappy IE! I now assume that this issue is caused by a bug deep inside the Winodws Http processing logic.
Has anyone another idea?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but I would suspect that IE is caching the GET requests.  Probably opening the Dev Tools disables this functionality, and all the GET requests are then sent.

Comment: yeah I thought of that, too. If it is caused by caching in IE, is it aswell in NET4.5? Is there a way to disable it in the W8 App?